# Agregar imagen determinada a gridview

Tags: android

estoy haciendo una app horoscopo , lo hice con un adaptador y me falta asignar cada imagen al signo para que quede en la grilla.

Puedo agregar la imagen en el arraylist ? o donde y con que parametros ?

adjunto main activity y el adapter

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
    import android.text.Layout;
      import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.KeyEvent;
       import android.view.View;
      import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
       import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
        import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
         import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
       import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
       import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
      import android.widget.AdapterView;
      import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private GridView gridView;
         private GridAdapter adapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("Aries");
        arrayList.add("Tauro");
        arrayList.add("Geminis");
        arrayList.add("Cancer");
        arrayList.add("Leo");
        arrayList.add("Virgo");
        arrayList.add("Libra");
        arrayList.add("Escorpio");
        arrayList.add("Sagitario");
        arrayList.add("Aries");
        arrayList.add("Acuario");
        arrayList.add("Piscis");


        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        adapter = new GridAdapter(this,arrayList );
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Descripcion.class);
                intent.putExtra("Nombre" , adapter.getItem(position).toString() ) ;
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }


   }
```

---

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridAdapter   extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList <String> arrayList;

    public GridAdapter (Context context, ArrayList <String> arrayList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;


    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid,null);

        }

        TextView tituloSigno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        tituloSigno.setText(arrayList.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: las imágenes las tienes en la carpeta drawable?

Answer (score -1):

Si las imágenes están en la carpeta drawable,
haz un array de imágenes en `onCreate` de la Activity y antes de
configurar el adapter:

```
 int[] imagenes = {R.drawable.tu_imagen1, ..., R.drawable.tu_imagen12};
```

y lo agregas al adapter:

```
 adapter = new GridAdapter(this,arrayList,imagenes);
```

Muy posiblemente te va marcar error (subrayado en rojo) esto es porque
el parámetro imagenes no esta en el constructor de la clase del Adaptador. Simplemente en 
el ícono rojo a la izq (como un foco rojo !) haz click y escoge la opción
`Add int[] as 3rd parameter`, para que lo agregue al constructor, o bien
lo ingresas manualmente.

En el GridAdapter declara el int array:

```
 private int []mImagen;
```

El constructor debe quedar así:

```
 public GridAdapter (Context context, ArrayList <String> arrayList, int[] imagenes){
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.mImagen = imagenes;
  }
```

Y en getView le asignas la imágen correspondiente:

```
 tuImageView.setImageResource(mImagen[position]);
```

Comment: oka , lo agregare